# Does anybody know of a free landscape / scenery generator?

Tags: 3d, landscape

For example along the lines of Vue d'Esprit 4 (or a blast from the past: VistaPro).

I have these but even the former is getting a bit old (!) and it would be interesting to experiment a bit again before possibly getting a fully paid up version.

It should include plants/trees.

I see [there should be a free version of Vue 10](http://www.cgchannel.com/2011/12/e-on-software-releases-free-versions-of-vue-10/), but I couldn't seem to find a working link. I liked Vue, but I'm open minded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it in a long time but there is Terragen 4 from Planetside:

https://planetside.co.uk/free-downloads/terragen-4-free-download/